# need to convert 2 binary strings to decimal than add them than convert them back to binary this is what i have so far

Tags: c++

I have been trying to convert 2 binary numbers to decimal add the two than convert the product back into binary using three functions not including the main. I think its a problem with my functions and returning them back into the main. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int binary_decimal(int num1); // first function definition for convertinf first binary number to decimal
int decimal_binary(int n); // function for turning the product of the 2 decimals back into binary
int binary_decimal2(int num2); // second function for turning second binary number into decimal 

int main () // main function
{

    int binary1,binary2,a,b,c; // creating variables for everyhting i though i would need


    cout<<"please enter in first binary number"<<endl; . // prompting for first binary value
    cin>>binary1;

    cout<<"please enter in your second binary number"<<endl; // prompting for second binary value
    cin>>binary2;


    a=binary_decimal(binary1);// where i returned the value from the functions into variables a and b
    b=binary_decimal2(binary2);
    c=a+b; //trying to add values of a and b for use in decimal to binary function

    cout<<"your added binary number is"<<decimal_binary(c)<<endl; // final output to give user there value

    getch(); // was using this to try and recieve values from functions 

    return 0;
}

int binary_decimal(int binary1) // Function to convert first binary to decimal//
{
    int decimal1=0, i=0, rem;
    while (binary1!=0)
    {
        rem = binary1%10;
        binary1/=10;
        decimal1 += rem*pow(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal1; // where i tried to return it back to main
}

int binary_decimal2(int binary2) // Function to convert the second binary value to decimal//
{
    int decimal2=0, i=0, rem;
    while (binary2!=0)
    {
        rem = binary2%10;
        binary2/=10;
        decimal2 += rem*pow(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal2; // where i tried to return it back to main 
}

int decimal_binary(int n)  // Function to convert decimal to binary.//
{
    int rem, i=1, binary=0;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        rem=n%2;
        n/=2;
        binary+=rem*i;
        i*=10;
    }
    return binary;// where i tried to return it back to main 
}
```

Comment: The two functions `binary_decimal` and `binary_decimal2` look like a pair of exact duplicate except for variable names. Why those two function exists, instead of only one? -- Ah, maybe due to somewhat strange problem statement?

Comment: I did [some test](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Qk71NRl0FZbbCjqp) with the functions, but I couldn't find any problems. What is your problem?

Comment: The dot after `cout<<"please enter in first binary number"<<endl;` should be removed in order to avoid compile error.

Comment: Using `pow()` for integer arithmetic looks strange for me. Why not use `(1<<i)` instead of `pow(2,i)` nor use the same method as what is used in `decimal_binary` (repeatedly multiplying)?